# Can we get better email notifications?

Tags: feature-request

When someone answers a question, serverfault emails me. When someone comments on my question, which can very likely contain relevant context to the question, I'd also like an email. Can you make it so there's at least an option to get emailed when someone comments on either my answer or any answer in a question? I'd rather have a flood of info when I really want to know something.

Comment: I'd be happy just to get an email when a new answer is posted. At this stage I get one once a week - sometimes - even when I've ticked the box.

Answer (score 4):

We will not be supporting this feature at this time

Note that the envelope next to your name lights up when there are comments on your posts, so you can always view your new comment responses there.

Comment: #Jeff could you elaborate a bit? The problem is we can't spend all day on SF. It would be nice to get notifications when there's activity on your questions?